# internet browser missing in 22.04

Tags: internet, default-browser

I have booted up the 22.04 version of Ubuntu.
and COULD NOT FIND ANY INTERNET BROWSER.
where did they hide it
or did they forget the most important part in this distro..
Browser not found in the list of available files, after clicking on the dots on the bottom left
..IT IS NORMALLY pinned to the home page

upset and mystified user

Comment: Firefox is installed by default. Please post a screenshot.

Comment: Firefox should be pinned to the top of your launcher, the bar on the left. Can't you find it or you can but it doesn't open? What exactly is the problem? The text of the question doesn't make much sense, please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: what options did you select when installing 22.04 LTS? [edit] your question to clarify this also. I installed 22.04 LTS on my scratch PC yesterday and by default, Firefox was installed so your question really doesn't make sense.

Comment: Does Firefox open when you run the `firefox` command from the terminal?

Comment: try > sudo apt install firefox in terminal

Comment: I installed "ubuntu-desktop" on top of server image. Firefox was not installed by default. Install from cli worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue where browser was not found. I ran the >sudo apt install firefox in terminal and that worked

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue.
for me the following simple commands worked:
sudo snap install firefox
or
sudo apt install firefox
hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me after flashing from raspberry pi OS.

First tried clicking the links in Thunderbird mail and `sudo apt-install firefox` didn't work.

I got firefox to open by searching for `default applications` and then it finally opened.

Yea I know lol, just click on the thing when you search it up.